# Browser specific sub-domain?

Tags: seo, subdomain

I was looking at [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25077/are-subdomains-for-mobile-specific-pages-or-localization-bad-for-seo) question and others similar, but I'm a bit unsure if the same applies for my case: I recently made a site which cuts for browser support at IE9. However the old site, which mine replaces, does have support all the way back to IE6.

Users on < IE8 will be redirected using JavaScript to **ie**.mydomain.com rather allowed trough to **www**.mydomain.com.

As the content is fairly similar on both sides I'm a bit worried about getting punished for duplicated content. For now I've disallowed the IE site for indexing altogether. But if there is something to gain of allowing indexing of both sites, that would of course be best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a terrible thing to do if you want to support legacy browsers. As long as you have it blocked from search engines crawlers you won't have to worry about duplicate content issues. And it isn't serving up special content just for the search engines because they are getting the same content as everyone else (nor is it done for the benefit of search engines) so it isn't black hat. So SEO-wise, this is fine.

Comment: So just to be clear: What you're saying is that I should just leave it like it is? Keep blocking crawlers for the ie site?

Comment: Yes. That is the best course of action.